# Are there plans to create a Portable Class Library for MVVMLight?

Tags: mvvm-light

Just wondering if Laurent has plans to migrate his code to the new portable class library Microsoft is providing us.

We have several projects in the pipeline that target both Windows 8 and WinPhone so this would be nice to have.

Comment: No idea why this one was closed. It is a crystal-clear question and I am wondering the same:
"Are there plans to create a *Portable Class Library* for MVVMLight?"

Comment: There is a portable version of MvvmLight available via nuget. The package is called Portable.MvvmLightLibs.  You can can see an example of how to use these in a Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 application here - http://blog.tattoocoder.com/2013/01/portable-mvvm-light-move-your-view.html